# Is Alchemy Server sided or client sided?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, alchemy

i know that action script is client sided. But i am very confused when i am using alchemy. Is alchemy client sided or server sided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client side.   It compiles to AVM2 bytecode, running on the same virtual machine as the rest of your ActionScript code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but the answer to this question is wrong. You could easily run alchemy generated code even alchemy + adobe AIR on server side:

http://code.google.com/p/redtamarin/issues/detail?id=6

http://code.google.com/p/redtamarin/wiki/ABC

Looking at the first link, since we can now use AIR capabilities in red tamarin you could write actionscript that uses a ServerSocket to listen and handle connections.

Also, you could still do this with a regular adobe AIR application deployed using the normal AIR runtime. You could, again, import your alchemy code, use it as necessary and you are running actionscript 3 on a server with the ability to natively handle socket connections via actionscript 3.

Comment: Believe it or not, at www.webkinz.com they used an AIR application server side to handle user T-Shirt designer application requests and take large vector graphics, assemble and render them out according to spec. This is really terrible, horribly disgusting example and it should not have been used for such a task (on a network with millions of users) but it was and although it was problematic due to load, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

While being rather new to Alchemy myself, from what I've seen it's both. If you're familiar with GWT for example, it has similarities to it.

I other words, it can run C/C++ code on the server, while being able to compile C/C++ code to ActionScript to be executed on the client.

Here's an article that explains it a bit more in-depth:
http://ncannasse.fr/blog/adobe_alchemy

Answer (score 0):

Alchemy or the XC API (it's official name) is dependent on the compiler and the runtime

for the compiler you HAVE TO use ASC2 (ActionScript Compiler 2.0)
AND
you HAVE TO compile to a SWF version 19 minimum
(eg. SWF19 is for Flash Player 11.6 and AIR 3.6)
see https://code.google.com/p/maashaack/wiki/FPAPI

this compiler will write special op codes to the final SWF file

for the runtime, any runtime using AVM2 (the ActionScript Virtual Machine)
at the condition the SWF is SWF19 or more will be able to interpret those special op codes

that means: Flash Player from 11.6, AIR from 3.6 and RedTamarin from v0.4 (about to be released)

put another way: Alchemy or the XC API, or fast memory ops etc.
are "special" bytecode operators (the compiler write them, the runtime read them)

see this article on how to use them
http://obtw.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/making-bytearray-faster/